# Thevenin Equivalent of circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I have a circuit that looks like the following. It appears to be simple-

[image]

What's the thevenin equivalent? I can't seem to simplify it as there are no common nodes that any of the resistors connect.

Comment: I would redraw this circuit first to clearly see what is parallel to what

Comment: R5 to R1 is as R4 to R2 - redraw to make the image simpler - this always helps.

Comment: If you redraw your schematic you will find that it is similar to a ["Wheatstone bridge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) (not invented by Wheatstone who only popularized another's invention) except that there is a resistor where a source usually is placed. It's a classic case suggesting that you memorize the \$\Delta-Y\$ conversions (both directions may be worth memorizing.) But it can also be solved out using nodal analysis, too. Are you familiar with nodal?

Comment: As others say, you can re-draw this to make it more clear. Also, this problem is often given with further condtions, like R1=R2=R4=R5. If you were given that information, you can simplify the circuit even further with a clever trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [delta-wye](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) transformation and then you’ll see parallel and series combinations of resistors you can reduce.

Comment: Works like a charm- thanks!